# TypeError at : / __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

i I'm beginner in learning Django, I got this error when i try to runserver:
 `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
the urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from users import views as user_views
from main.views import about, ListView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('', ListView, name='PostListViews'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView


def blog(request):
     context = {
         'posts': Post.objects.all()
     }
     return render(request=request,
                   template_name='main/blog.html',
                   context=context)


class PostListViews(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/blog.html'


def about(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/about.html')
```

i don't know where the error comes from please explain to me and Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It should be `ListView.as_view()`

Comment: i change it like this ` path('', ListView.as_view(), name='PostListViews'),`  
 but they show me    `ListView is missing a QuerySet. Define ListView.model, ListView.queryset, or override ListView.get_queryset().
`

Comment: @khadijaouakkaha marks my answer as accepted if it has helped you

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan thank u for your help but they show me `NameError: name 'PostListViews' is not defined`

Comment: @khadijaouakkaha you will have to import `PostListViews` into your  urls.py file

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan thank you so mushit's work  i forget to import it :)

Comment: @khadijaouakkaha haha,happens alot with me too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

`path('', ListView, name='PostListViews'),`

write

```
path('', PostListViews.as_view(), name='PostListViews'),
```

Try it